# Staging xml in snowflake

Tags: xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, staging

I am trying to stage xml data from S3 into snowflake. I have successfully created the stage, while querying the data I am getting below given error, upon checking i found some characters are not per UTF-8 encoding in the data.

**Error parsing XML: missing first byte in UTF-8 sequence File 'data.xml', line 13583, character 29 Row 300 starts at line 13574, column $1**

I tried IGNORE_UTF8_ERRORS = TRUE option in staging, the data is not coming right.
we dont want to lose on the data, it seems like the encoding here is “ISO-8859-1”.

Anyone having any suggestion on how to fix this thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your source data uses a different encoding than UTF-8 then you can specify this in your COPY INTO statement as explained in our [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html).

[image]

The file format also has a parameter for the encoding, see [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html).